# If I use a CC-BY-SA artwork as part of my book cover art, do I need to share my entire book cover art under a similar license?

Tags: license, creative-commons, copyleft, cc-by-sa

I'm confused about the share alike part of the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license which states:

> share alike – If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same or compatible license as the original.

The upper part of my book cover is an unmodified CC-BY-SA 3.0 image, covering about 60% of the cover, while the bottom 40% features stylized text.

Questions

1. Since I used the unmodified CC-BY-SA 3.0 image as part of my art cover, my question is whether the combined cover is still considered a remixed or transformed work, and therefore whether I need to share the entire book cover under a similar license?
2. How does slightly cropping the CC-BY-SA 3.0 image as part of 60% of my art cover affect the licensing conditions?

Comment: Your question depends on local copyright law and you might need to consult a lawyer. Have you read [this](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#when-is-my-use-considered-an-adaptation) and [this](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-is-an-adaptation)?

Comment: Also, could you read [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/9219/458) and let us know if it answers your question?